# OOM-Killer called every now and then

Tags: debian, apache-http-server, passenger

I have a dedicated server where I've installed `apache2`, as well as `rails-passenger`. Although i have 2GBs of RAM and most times about 1,5GB is free, there are some random times where I loose `ssh` and generic connectivity because `oom-killer` is killing processes.

I suppose there is a memory leak but I cannot find out where it comes from. `oom-killer` kills `apache2`, `mysql`, `passenger` and whatever.

Yesterday, I did a `cat syslog | grep -c oom-killer` and got 57 occurences!

It seems that something seriously destroys the memory. Once I reboot, everything comes back to normal. I suspect that it can be related to `passenger`, but I'm still trying to figure it out.

Can you think of another cause, or do you have anything to suggest that will make the leak identification procedure easier? I was even thinking of writing a bash script, to be run with `cron` for like every 5 minutes.

Comment: Yeah, until you run a script pinpointing which processes are growing, when, and how fast, it's not an answerable question.

Answer (score 1):

The Linux kernel by default overcommit memory so that sometimes a program will successfully allocate memory not available and the OOM will kick in and kill a random process instead. Disabling this would perhaps allow you do perhaps identify what application steals memory. E.g. if a application is suddenly allocating a huge chunk of memory it will fail (and hopefully return a error message). Other applications may fail allocating memory as well so you should watch out for a false positive.

echo 2 > /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory